# How Count Token minted in a range (For NFT Smart Contract)

Tags: solidity, contract-development, erc-721, nft

By advance sorry for asking and thanks for your help, I find/try to resolve my problem from a few days.

I try to add on my smart contract a function to count the number of mint on a specific range (to limit the mint possible on a free mint period from a unique wallet).

For example, i open a free mint period from token n°100 to n°150, i need to limit the mint on a unique wallet at 5.

I try to start this from tokensByOwner function, maybe is not a good solution, if you have an idea let me know

```
function tokensByOwner(address _owner) external view returns(uint256[] memory ) {
        uint256 tokenCount = balanceOf(_owner);
        if (tokenCount == 0) {
            return new uint256[](0);
        } else {
            uint256[] memory result = new uint256[](tokenCount);
            uint256 index;
            for (index = 0; index < tokenCount; index++) {
                result[index] = tokenOfOwnerByIndex(_owner, index);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

I think i need to add an if in a for loop but maybe its wrong

```
if (index >= RANGE_MIN_TOKEN_FOR_FREE_MINT && index <= RANGE_MAX_TOKEN_FOR_FREE_MINT) {
```

I have try to out of the loops with this code but my test are not ok ( result after max range is 0 0 0 .....)

```
                if (index >= RANGE_MAX_TOKEN_FOR_FREE_MINT) {
                // Exit loop with break
                break;
```

########

Hi,

I have again try with differents test/parameter, is not again good.

```
     function atokensByOwnerAAAA(address _owner) external view returns(uint256) {
        uint256 tokenCount = balanceOf(_owner);
            uint256 index;
            uint256 count;
            for (index = 0; index < tokenCount && index < RANGE_MAX_TOKEN_FOR_FREE_MINT; index++) {
                if (index >= RANGE_MIN_TOKEN_FOR_FREE_MINT) {
                    count++;
                }
                if (index > RANGE_MAX_TOKEN_FOR_FREE_MINT) {
                // Exit loop with break
                break;
                }
            } 
        return count;
        }

   function atokensByOwnerBBBB(address _owner) external view returns(uint256) {
        uint256 tokenCount = balanceOf(_owner);
            uint256 index;
            uint256 count;
            for (index = 0; index < tokenCount && index < RANGE_MAX_TOKEN_FOR_FREE_MINT; index++) {
                /*if (index >= RANGE_MIN_TOKEN_FOR_FREE_MINT) {*/
                    count++;
                /*}*/
                if (index > RANGE_MAX_TOKEN_FOR_FREE_MINT) {
                // Exit loop with break
                break;
                }
            } 
        return count;
        }

    function atokensByOwnerCCCC(address _owner) external view returns(uint256) {
        uint256 tokenCount = balanceOf(_owner);
            uint256 index;
            uint256 count;
            for (index = 0; index < tokenCount && index <= RANGE_MAX_TOKEN_FOR_FREE_MINT; index++) {
                if (index >= RANGE_MIN_TOKEN_FOR_FREE_MINT) {
                    count++;
                }
            } 
        return count;
        }
```

do you have an idea?

#########

Hi Coliga, thanks for the help.

yes it's the objectiv.

I have try to add your code but I have an error on remix

```
    mapping (address => uint256) addressToNumberOfTokensMinted;
    bool freeMintPeriod = true;

    function mintforfree(uint256 _count) external {
        addressToNumberOfTokensMinted += _count;
        if(freeMintPeriod) {
            require(addressToNumberOfTokensMinted[msg.sender] < 6, "No free mints left!");
    }

        uint256 totalSupply = totalSupply();
        for(uint256 i = 0; i < _count; i++){
            _safeMint(msg.sender, totalSupply + i);
        }
}
```

error return ==>

```
from solidity:
TypeError: Types in storage containing (nested) mappings cannot be assigned to.
  --> test2.sol:41:9:
   |
41 |         addressToNumberOfTokensMinted += _count;
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

from solidity:
TypeError: Operator += not compatible with types mapping(address => uint256) and uint256
  --> test2.sol:41:9:
   |
41 |         addressToNumberOfTokensMinted += _count;
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

solution by myself (tested ok)

```
    function tokensByOwnerForFreeMint(address _owner) external view returns(uint256) {
        uint256 tokenCount = balanceOf(_owner);
            uint256 index;
            uint256 indextwo;
            uint256 count;
            for (index = 0; index < tokenCount; index++) {
                indextwo = tokenOfOwnerByIndex(_owner, index);
                if (indextwo >= RANGE_MIN_TOKEN_FOR_FREE_MINT && indextwo <= RANGE_MAX_TOKEN_FOR_FREE_MINT) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            return count;
        }
```

Comment: My bad, I edited my answer. Because you didn't know what the problem was, I assume you are not familiar with [mappings](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.4.21/types.html#mappings). So, I suggest you to first look into what a [mapping](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.4.21/types.html#mappings) exactly is.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your question is: How to let every unique address mint a maximum of 5 NFTs for free during the free mint period?

This can be done by storing the amount of tokens every address minted. Then in the mint function check if `msg.sender` minted <6 tokens.

Example:

```
mapping (address => uint256) addressToNumberOfTokensMinted;
bool freeMintPeriod = true;

function mint(uint256 _count) external {
    addressToNumberOfTokensMinted[msg.sender] += _count;
    if(freeMintPeriod) {
        require(addressToNumberOfTokensMinted[msg.sender] < 6, "No free mints left!");
    }

    // Mint tokens
}
```